# Weird mix of using the Barrier KVM and VirtualBox breaks a Keyboard layout

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, keyboard-layout, kvm-switch

I'm having an oddly specific problem where:

I have two computers, one with Windows 10, the other with EndeavourOS Linux. I use both of them through the VKVM software Barrier so that I can use the keyboard and mouse connected to the W10 machine into the Linux machine. And an important factor is that the W10 machine has an US-Inter. keyboard, whereas the Linux machine has a Latin American/Argentine layout, Barrier translates the inputs of the US keyboard correctly whenever I type something in the Linux machine from the W10 machine, but for this, I must re-change the layout from the Linux machine to `latam` through the command `setxkbmap latam`.

In the Linux machine, because it's more powerful than the W10 machine, I installed VirtualBox and set up a bunch of VMs, among them two Windows guests, one with XP for recreational purposes, and one with Windows 10 (specifically Tiny10) for using work-related software.

I also installed other guests, specifically Haiku and some Linux distros, and these guest machines work as intended, writing from the W10 machine into these VMs they write everything correctly.

The problem arises with the Windows machines. As, for some reason, for the US layout in both the XP and the W10 guests machines, the special keys layouts are broken, giving me for example a 3/4 symbol instead of the [ symbol, this is kind of intended as the translation directly correlates with the host(the Linux machine)'s keyboard layout, but if I change it to the Latin American layout, it has a weird and very specific behavior.

The < (Shift + ,), @ (Shift + 2), ~ (Shift + `), and the [ and ] keys don't work, but the others work, like { and } (Shift + [ and ] respectively), !, #, , and >.

Does anyone know why it has this behavior?